# Using VBA code how to extract Non HTML data content residing under each heading from a word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

How to extract text and non text data content (ex: Tables, pictures) associated with each heading irrespective of heading style?

With below code I am able to reach out to each header, post that I am failing to extract content associated with that heading:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Main()
        Dim strFile As String
        Dim oWord As Word.Application
        Dim oWdoc As Word.Document
        Dim oPar As Word.Paragraph
        Dim rng As Word.Range
        strFile = "C:\Users\SQVA\Desktop\My_Work\MyTest3.docx"
        'Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        Set oWord = New Word.Application
        Set oWdoc = oWord.Documents.Open(strFile)
    Call Get_Heading_Name(oWord, oWdoc, strFile, rng)
    Call Close_Word(oWord, oWdoc)
End Sub  

   Sub Get_Heading_Name(oWord As Word.Application, oWdoc As Word.Document, strFile As String, rng As Word.Range)
    oWord.Visible = True
    Dim astrHeadings As Variant
    Dim strText As String
    Dim intItem As Integer
    Set rng = oWdoc.Content
    astrHeadings = _
    oWdoc.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)
    For intItem = LBound(astrHeadings) To UBound(astrHeadings)
            strText = Trim$(astrHeadings(intItem))
            'Debug.Print CStr(strText)
            'Debug.Print astrHeadings(intItem).
            Dim my_String As String
            Dim intLevel
            If CStr(strText) <> "" Then
                my_String = Right(strText, Len(strText) - InStr(strText, " "))
                intLevel = GetLevel(CStr(astrHeadings(intItem)))
               ' Call GetHeadingNextText(oWdoc, my_String)
               ' Debug.Print my_String
               ' Debug.Print intLevel
               ' rng.Style = "Heading " & intLevel
                Dim sTextSearch() As String
                Dim StrHdTxt1
                Dim nStart As Long, nEnd As Long, n As Long, k As Long
                Dim wdTable
                Dim wdTbl As Word.Table, wdCell As Word.cell, wdCellRng As Word.Range
                Dim wdIshp As Word.InlineShape, wdShp As Word.Shape, StrHdTxt As String
                oWdoc.Range(0, 0).Select
                With oWord.Selection.Find
                    .Style = oWdoc.Styles("Heading " & intLevel)
                    .Text = my_String
                    If .Execute Then
                        'Debug.Print "Found"
                        Call SelectHeadingandContent(oWdoc, oWord)
                    End If
                End With
            End If
    Next intItem
End Sub  

Sub Close_Word(oWord As Word.Application, oWdoc As Word.Document)
        oWdoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
        oWord.Quit
        Set oWdoc = Nothing
        Set oWord = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function GetLevel(strItem As String) As Integer
    ' Return the heading level of a header from the
    ' array returned by Word.

    ' The number of leading spaces indicates the
    ' outline level (2 spaces per level: H1 has
    ' 0 spaces, H2 has 2 spaces, H3 has 4 spaces.

    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim strOriginal As String
    Dim longDiff As Integer

    ' Get rid of all trailing spaces.
    strOriginal = RTrim$(strItem)

    ' Trim leading spaces, and then compare with
    ' the original.
    strTemp = LTrim$(strOriginal)

    ' Subtract to find the number of
    ' leading spaces in the original string.
    longDiff = Len(strOriginal) - Len(strTemp)
    GetLevel = (longDiff / 2) + 1
End Function

Sub SelectHeadingandContent(oWdoc As Word.Document, oWord As Word.Application)
Dim headStyle 'As Style
' Checks that you have selected a heading. If you have selected multiple paragraphs,checks only the first one. If you have selected a heading, makes sure the whole paragraph is selected and records the style. If not, exits the subroutine.
If oWdoc.Styles(oWord.Selection.Paragraphs(1).Style).ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel < wdOutlineLevelBodyText Then
    Set headStyle = oWord.Selection.Paragraphs(oWord.Selection.Paragraphs.Count).Style
    oWord.Selection.Expand wdParagraph
Else: Exit Sub
End If

' Turns off screen updating so the the screen does not flicker.

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Loops through the paragraphs following your selection, and incorporates them into the selection as long as they have a higher outline level than the selected heading (which corresponds to a lower position in the document hierarchy). Exits the loop if there are no more paragraphs in the document.
Dim My_Text As String
My_Text = ""
Do While oWdoc.Styles(oWord.Selection.Paragraphs(oWord.Selection.Paragraphs.Count).Next.Style).ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel > headStyle.ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel
     'Debug.Print oWord.Selection.Paragraphs(oWord.Selection.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Text
     oWord.Selection.MoveEnd wdParagraph
     ' Debug.Print oWord.Selection.Paragraphs(oWord.Selection.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Text
     My_Text = My_Text + vbCr + oWord.Selection.Paragraphs(oWord.Selection.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Text
     If oWord.Selection.Paragraphs(oWord.Selection.Paragraphs.Count).Next Is Nothing Then Exit Do
Loop
Debug.Print My_Text
' Turns screen updating back on.

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Word isn't really designed to be used like this, and as far as graphics go if they're formatted with text wrap you can't be sure they're VISIBLY where you think they are. You also have to know exactly what kinds of things you want to address unless you plan to "walk" the document character-by-character. For this kind of thing, using the WordOpenXML file format is the better bet. What is it, more exactly, that you need to do? IOW *why* do you want only the non-text content?

Comment: Thanks Cindy for your input. Let me try to explain what I want to achieve.conside a word document with section 1,section 2,section 3,section 4 headings with style "heading 1".under each section heading there is data content both text and non text. my output should like below:  Name: section 1 Data: section 1 ( text + non text ) Name: section 2 data: section 2( text +non text) so on name: section 4 data: section 4 data( text + non text)

Comment: I tried to retrieve name of each heading having style "heading 1" but unfortunately could not retrieve , could you provide help on get the names of  headings having a specific style in a word document.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the Heading1 ranges and their 'non-text' objects, as you call them, with code like:

```
Sub Read_Heading_Contents()
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, wdRng As Word.Range
Dim wdTbl As Word.Table, wdCell As Word.Cell, wdCellRng As Word.Range
Dim wdIshp As Word.InlineShape, wdShp As Word.Shape, StrHdTxt As String
Const strFile As String = "C:\Users\SQVA\Desktop\My_Work\MyTest3.docx"
With wdApp
  .Visible = True
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(Filename:=strFile, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc
    With .Range
      With .Find
        .Style = wdStyleHeading1
        .Text = ""
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute
      End With
      If .Find.Found = False Then
        MsgBox "No 'Heading 1' style found."
      Else
        Do While .Find.Found = True
          StrHdTxt = .Duplicate.Text: MsgBox StrHdTxt
          Set wdRng = .Duplicate.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\HeadingLevel")
          For Each wdTable In .Tables
            With wdTbl
              For Each wdCell In .Range.Cells
                Set wdCellRng = wdCell.Range
                wdCellRng.End = wdCellRng.End - 1
                MsgBox wdCellRng.Text
              Next
            End With
          Next
          For Each wdIshp In wdRng.InlineShapes
            With wdIshp
              If Not .TextEffect Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox .TextEffect.Text
              End If
            End With
          Next
          For Each wdShp In wdRng.ShapeRange
            With wdShp
              If Not .TextFrame Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox .TextFrame.TextRange.Text
              End If
            End With
          Next
          .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
          .Find.Execute
        Loop
      End If
    End With
    .Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
  End With
  .Quit
End With
Set wdRng = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

The above code includes message boxes to display the heading names and whatever it finds in the heading range's 'non-text' content. I'll leave it to you to turn the textbox output into whatever else you want it to be. Of course, not all inline & floating shapes have text; the loops find those, too, but I have no idea how you intend to 'read' those.

Comment: Hi Macropod, Thanks a lot for taking time to answer my question.I tried provided script and got termination during script execution. I tried it in another way as edited in question , could you please check it and let me know how to extract text and non text content

Comment: Hi Macropod, I am getting "Microsoft Word has Stopped Working" message and word document is going to Not Responsing state,Unfortunately I am unable to attach screenshot

Comment: As I said: *You may need to do some debugging of your own*. For example, you might start by deleting the 'For Each wdIshp' and 'For Each wdShp' loops and confirming whether the code as posted processes your tables correctly, then re-test with whatever modification you've made to that part of the code, before reinstating the 'For Each wdIshp' and testing that in the same way and, finally, doing the same with the 'For Each wdShp' loop.

Comment: Hi Macropod, I did step by step debugging and understood that code is looking for contents between 2 headers of style( "header1"), Code is failing when it is attempting to extract non text data present between headers of style "Heading 1" and "Non Heading 1" ,Instead of searching code between two headings of same style , can we modify provided code to iterate through all the headings present in document irrespective of their style and get the content (body) under those headings irrespective of whether content is text,image,table,html etc? Is there a way I can add sample word document here?

Comment: Micropod, thank you for inputs. I tried from my side and is able to achieve below 2 things: 1. getting names of all the headings 2.irrespective of heading style I am able to find heading and navigate to all headings , only part which I am unable to get is upon navigating to a specific  heading  how to extract the content residing under that heading ( content can be text , non text ) , can we use word copy functionality to copy the content between this heading and next heading to a clipboard?

Comment: The code I posted already shows you how to get all the content for a particular heading. The additional loops exist only because of the 'non-text' strictures you place on it.

Comment: Hi Macropod, I have updated question with the latest code, this code will iterate to all the headings and will extract the residing text content without any issues, could you please give me some guidance on how I can further extend this code to extract non text content residing under every heading.